# IE9 position: fixed with vertical scrollbar issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, overflow, css-position

I'm having an issue in IE9 (which is in IE7 and IE8 as well; not in IE6 and below because they don't support `position: fixed`) in which if I add `overflow-y: scroll` to an element within a `position: fixed` element, the scrollbar on the `overflow-y: scroll` element occupies some of the width of the element instead of adding the necessary number of pixels to the width to the element to make room for the scrollbar.

The following HTML/CSS demonstrates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IE9 position: fixed issue</title>
    <style>
      body, div, html, p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .fixed {
        left: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
      }
      .outer {
        height: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      .inner {
        background: yellow;
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="stats">
    </div>
    <div class="fixed">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var stats = document.querySelector('.stats'),
        outer = document.querySelector('.outer'),
        inner = document.querySelector('.inner');

      stats.innerHTML = 
        '<p>Outer width: ' + outer.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px</p>';

      stats.innerHTML += 
        '<p>Inner width: ' + inner.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px</p>';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you run this code in Chrome, FF, etc., you will get an outer width of 317px and an inner width of 300px. Also, there will be no horizontal scrollbar.

However, if you run the same code in IE9, both widths will be reported out as 300px, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to fix this problem in IE9?
Thank you very much.